# Save As in Word will overwrite the currently open file, but not Excel

Tags: microsoft-word

I have long used the SaveAs feature to force me to change the file name, preventing me from overwriting the currently open file. This is true in Excel, but Word has changed at some point, and it will let me overwrite the file I have open without forcing or warning me to rename it. When did that change and why? Why would Excel work the way I expect then?

Comment: I just 'save as'ed without renaming in Excel. I don't think it does what you think it does.

Comment: Right, Excel is correct, Word is broken. Why?

Comment: I meant they work the same, but after reviewing, Word doesn't ask me "Are you sure?!". I've searched the 'save' options and don't see anywhere where you can force it to ask this.

Comment: I thought too that Word and Excel locked a file for editing when it was opened which prevented it and any other program from overriding the file, but they have changed this. You do still get the error message if you open the document in a different window and try to override it.